# Use browserfiy'es watchify to watch multiple files

Tags: linux, windows, npm, browserify, watchify

I want to watch and output as following on Windows and Linux:

```
watchify ./src/login/login.js -o ./public/js/login.js -v && watchify ./src/unlock/unlock.js -o ./public/js/unlock.js -v && watchify ./src/admin/admin.js -o ./public/js/admin.js -v
```

Why in `./public/js` directory I get just 1 file: `dashboard.js` instead of all of them?

Answer (score 5):

add `start` before each `watchify` command to open it into a separate window.

```
start watchify ./src/login/login.js -o ./public/js/login.js -v && start watchify ./src/unlock/unlock.js -o ./public/js/unlock.js -v && start watchify ./src/admin/admin.js -o ./public/js/admin.js -v
```